PHP - replace text and check for file?
I have this simple line of php
$text  = preg_replace("/\\ii(.*?)\\<>/", "<img scr='img/$1'>", $text);

Where I change II30.jpgII to <img scr='img/30.jpg'>, and it works fine.
But what I need, is to also check if there is a file called 30.txt, and if so, print the text below the image. I simply can't figure out how do do that - maybe I'm all wrong using preg_replace anyway?
What I acually need is a way to change \<img>30.jpg\<img>  to <img scr='img/30.jpg'>, but I could not figure out how to search for \<img> so ended up using II instead :-)
And then call a function image_text_print("img/30.txt"), if the file exists, insert the return just below the image.
It not so well explained, but I hope you understand what I look for :-)

Edit
Instead maybe I should somehow search the $text for xxxxx, and then

check for file xxxxx.txt
read the file xxxxx.txt file
make the changes in $text to

(text from xxxxx.txt file)


But I can't figure out how to search for content between multiple  and , in $text :-/
Jorgensen

Maybe preg_replace('/\\\\<img>(.*?)\\\\<img>/', "<img scr='img/\$1'>", $text)?

Hi Wiktor - it did not work for me - I get

"30.jpg"

using the above line.
the II30.jpgII is ok, my biggest issue is - how do I check if there is a 30.txt file, and if so, how do I include the text from that file, under the image?
Jorgensen

Show me your exact code.

$beskrivelse  = preg_replace('/\\(.*?)\\/', "", $beskrivelse);
But as I wrote in the edit above, the right way would probably be to search for xxxx.jpg, in the string - then extract every xxxx.jpg, and replace it with the image and related text from the text file.
But I can't figure out how to find and extract all xxx.jpg, and get the values between the  in the string :-/

What is in $beskrivelse? See https://3v4l.org/i4CeR to understand how it works.

I would use preg_replace_callback here. Then you can pass your match to a custom callback function, which creates the img element HTML first, and can then check if a text file with a corresponding name exists - and if so, read its content, and appends it to the return value.

wiktor - $beskrivelse (in danish) is the actual variable name I use - $text was just an example. Thanks wiktor - that works now.

@c3roe - thanks - I did not know of that function - I will look into that - thanks!

This question does not contain a good, clear [mcve].

sorry mickmackusa - im not a programmer or experienced user of stackoverflow :-/

This is my proposed solution using preg_match_all instead of preg_replace or preg_replace_callback. I have made a couple of assumptions: 1) The images are always digits followed by dot jpg, and 2) There may be other text in between the images. I'm sure you can adjust those as required.
//sample text to search and replace on
$text = 'Some other text \<img>30.jpg\<img> something in between \<img>50.jpg\<img> something else \<img>40.jpg\<img>';

//initialize an array to hold the matches
$matches = [];

//this is here to mock up the function you said you needed to call
//this code simply fetches the file contents
function image_text_print($filename)
{
  return file_get_contents($filename);
}

//find all matches of \<img>30.jpg\<img> where 30 can be any number made up of 1 or more digits (adjust the regex to your requirements)
if(preg_match_all('#\\\<img>(\d+).jpg\\\<img>#', $text,$matches))
{
  //preg_match_all gives us 2 arrays, one with the matched text and one with the image numbers
  foreach($matches[0] as $matchInd=>$matchText)
  {
    //build up the replacement text
    $replacement = '<img scr="img/'.$matches[1][$matchInd].'.jpg">';
    
    //create the filename and then check if it exists
    $filename = 'img/'.$matches[1][$matchInd].'.txt';
    if(is_file($filename))
    {
      //if the file exists call your function and append results
      $replacement .= image_text_print($filename);
    }

    //finally replace the matched text
    $text = str_replace($matchText,$replacement,$text);
  }
}


Hi Mark
Thanks - that seems to do the job!
Now I just need to dive into how it works :-)
Jorgensen
